# Selenium web test: get a list of links names from html

Tags: java, selenium, junit, testng

How do I fill map by a list of links names from a html code.
clearly, I've this code HTML:

```
<div id="element-list">
<dl  id="element-template" class="element">
    <dd class="element element-1-0">                        
        <a class="element-name" href="#">TEXT1</a> 
    </dd>       
    <dd class="element element-1-0">     
        <a  class="element-name" href="#">TEXT2</a>  
    </dd>       
    <dd class="element element-1-0">                      
        <a  class="element-name" href="#">TEXT3</a> 
    </dd>        
</dl>
```

I would like to recover in a map java Text1, Text2, Text3.

I get the first link (text1) in this manner:

```
String elmt = selenium.getText("css=a.element-name");
```

and this is normal, but I need to check all elements.

Could anyone help me by telling me the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 int count = selenium.getXpathCount("//a[@class='element-name']").intValue();
 for(int i =1 ; i <= count ; i ++){
         System.out.println(selenium.getText("//dd["+i+"]/a"));
 }
```

Does this help ?